How to dynamically remove a default object from 'IEnumerable<T>' on a REST controller
I've got a REST endpoint that receives the class EntityInsertRequest
public class EntityInsertRequest
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class EntityFieldInsertRequest
{
    public string DatabaseField { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

How can I create a filter or override in the initialization of the object to remove a default object of the list, in this case a default object of the list would be:
{
    "databaseField": "",
    "description": ""
}

And I would be sending:
{
    "description": "FooBar",
    "fields": [
        {
            "databaseField": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "databaseField": "Foo",
            "description": "Bar"
        }
    ]
}

I would like it to be instantiated with an empty list and be dynamically replicated for other endpoints.
I can't alter how it's send and remove the object on the sender's side, it needs to be on the back-end.
I've tried to create a JsonConverter<IEnumerable<T>>:
public class NullableIEnumerableOverride<T> : JsonConverter<IEnumerable<T>> where T : class
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert) && typeToConvert != typeof(string) && typeToConvert.GenericTypeArguments[0].IsClass;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<T> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var internalOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
     
        var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<T>>(ref reader);

        if (list == null || !list.Any())
        {
            return  (IEnumerable<T>)CreateEmptyInstance(typeToConvert);
        }

        // can't get properties of generic object with typeof(T).GetProperties()
        //bool allFieldsAreDefault = list.All(item =>
        //{
        //   var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        //    return properties.All(prop =>
        //    {
        //        var value = prop.GetValue(item);
        //        var defaultValue = GetDefault(prop.PropertyType);
        //        return Equals(value, defaultValue);
        //    });
        //});
        //return allFieldsAreDefault ? (IEnumerable<T>)CreateEmptyInstance(typeToConvert) : list;

        return list;
    }

    private static object CreateEmptyInstance(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        if (typeToConvert.IsGenericType && typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
        {
            Type elementType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(listType) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to create instance of type {listType}.");
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type {typeToConvert} is not supported.");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable<T>? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNullValue();
            return;
        }

        JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new()
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        };

        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, jsonOptions);
    }

    private object? GetDefault(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
    }
}

And in the program.cs, I have:
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new NullableIEnumerableOverride<object>());
});

Because I want to use it on other endpoints and set it as a generic object on program.cs, I get this cast error:

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Logic.Request.Entity.EntityFieldInsertRequest]'.
at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidCastException_DeserializeUnableToAssignValue(Type typeOfValue, Type declaredType)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.g__ThrowUnableToCastValue|50_0[T](Object value)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.UnboxOnRead[T](Object value)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo1.ContinueDeserialize(ReadBufferState& bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack)
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo1.DeserializeAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo1.DeserializeAsObjectAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value, Object container)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)


Wouldn't serializing into a generic object, followed by ending up in a concrete type have a performance impact? I'm not 100% sure from the code what properties your other concrete classes have but could that not trigger boxing/unboxing and adding to the heap as well?

If other endpoints use their own request objects with similar requirement, I still would not go with a single solution. You could end up with code hard to maintain, test, and can't be easily updated if a single request needs specific changes down the road.
For EntityInsertRequest add a backing field and then have your setter ignore "default" items: set { _fields = value.Where(field => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.DatabaseField) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.Description)).ToList(); do the same for the other request. Easy to maintain, unit-tested and flexible.

Alterantively for more control over when to apply the logic to remove the default items, if not needed every time, an Action Filter containing that logic could work for that.
Action Filter could also be expanded to check the types in the context and based on the request type different "resolvers" could be called that each know how to deal with their exact request object's "default" items. Its a little more work but each abstraction is easily maintained and testable.

After playing around with the given code, I could not figure the generic converter out.
However, there are other options.
Request Level
You could add the logic directly to the Request object.
That would remove the "default" fields every time you set the fields value.
This will work and a test can also be easily written to verify it.
You will have to update each Request object off course and there is no flexibility if you ever want an instance not with "default" fields removed.
public class EntityInsertRequest
{
    private IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest> _fields = [];

    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest> Fields
    {
        get => _fields;
        set { 
            _fields = value
                .Where(field => 
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.DatabaseField) || 
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.Description))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}

If you want more flexibility as to when to remove the "default" fields, you can implement an Action Filter.
The Action Filter will be able to process the request object and depending on the concrete type call the matching "Remover" (or what ever you may want to call it) to remove the "default" items as needed.
Action Filter
public class NullableIEnumerableFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public NullableIEnumerableFilter(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        foreach (var argument in context.ActionArguments.Values)
        {
            switch (argument)
            {
                case EntityInsertRequest insertRequest:
                    var remover = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(INullableIEnumerableRemover<EntityInsertRequest>)) as INullableIEnumerableRemover<EntityInsertRequest>;
                    remover?.Run(insertRequest);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) { }
}

Remover Interface
public interface INullableIEnumerableRemover<T>
{
    void Run(T request);
}

The EntityInsertRequest Remover
public class EntityInsertRequestNullableIEnumerableRemover : INullableIEnumerableRemover<EntityInsertRequest>
{
    public void Run(EntityInsertRequest request)
    {
        request.Fields = request.Fields
            .Where(f => 
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.DatabaseField) ||
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Description))
            .ToList();
    }
}

Usage/Test
The Filter and removers have to be registered off course. How might be different, depending on project type etc... I used a Web API for testing so it looked like this:
builder.Services.AddScoped<NullableIEnumerableFilter>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<INullableIEnumerableRemover<EntityInsertRequest>, EntityInsertRequestNullableIEnumerableRemover>();

I tested this locally by creating a simple endpoint that responds with the fields to verify the "default" was removed. The ServiceFilter attribute can also be applied at the controller level.
[HttpPost(Name = "AddEntity")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(NullableIEnumerableFilter))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(EntityInsertRequest request)
{
    return Ok(request.Fields);
}

My .http file passed the data like this:
POST {{CollectionInit_HostAddress}}/entities/
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "description": "my description",
    "fields": [
        {
            "databaseField": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "databaseField": "db field 1",
            "description": "description 1"
        },
        {
            "databaseField": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "databaseField": "db field 2",
            "description": "description 2"
        }
    ]
}

Response received was this:
[
  {
    "databaseField": "db field 1",
    "description": "description 1"
  },
  {
    "databaseField": "db field 2",
    "description": "description 2"
  }
]

I also verified it works when passing only "default" items or no items at all.
Summary
While this requires an implementation of a remover per request object and will be more work than removing "default" fields in each Request object directly, it also gives you the flexibility to only apply the logic when needed.
Each implementation is still clear, easily maintained and testable.
Having a single generic converter might be less work, it will also be less flexible if requirements arise where a specific request might now need a more specific condition, which can lead to a converter that will grow quickly and become hard to maintain and harder to test for each type and scenario.

To dynamically remove the default object from the IEnumerable list in your .NET controller, you can modify the EntityInsertRequest before further processing. This can be done in a model binder or directly within the controller action.
Within the controller using LINQ to filter out default objects:
Filter the Fields: Before saving or further processing the request, filter the Fields to remove any default or empty entries.
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult InsertEntity([FromBody] EntityInsertRequest request)
{
    // Remove default/empty objects from the Fields list
    request.Fields = request.Fields?.Where(field => 
        !(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.DatabaseField) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.Description))
    ).ToList() ?? new List<EntityFieldInsertRequest>();

    // Continue processing the cleaned request
    // Your save or business logic here

    return Ok();
}

This approach ensures that any EntityFieldInsertRequest objects where both DatabaseField and Description are empty or null will be removed from the Fields collection.
If the Fields collection is null, it will initialize an empty list to avoid null reference exceptions.

The JSON converter will be invoked when the type matches exactly with the generic type provided for JsonConverter, which in your case is object.
Let's first focus on problem at hand - you want to handle in custom way collection IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest>, so let's start by defining custom converter for that type.
Further explanations are in code in comments:
// Here we explicitly state that we want to override serialization
// of IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest>
public class NullableIEnumerableOverride : JsonConverter<IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest>>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert == typeof(IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest>);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest> Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader, 
        Type typeToConvert, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Here we must to "copy the original options", in order to
        // preserve all ASP.NET specific configurations. Without it
        // we would get nulls in most places.
        var internalOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        // Here we must remove this converter, if we want to pass the options
        // to another serializer. Without it, the converter will
        // call itself in result, resulting in stack overflow exception.
        internalOptions.Converters.Remove(this);
        // Perform regular deserialization.
        var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest>>(ref reader, internalOptions);
        // Filter out objects that do not pass our condition.
        list = list
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.DatabaseField) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Description))
            .ToArray();

        return list;
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer, 
        IEnumerable<EntityFieldInsertRequest> value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

